# NLTK 3 release 4 API documentation

Tags: nltk, api-doc

Hi all just a quick question. I am working with nltk Version 3 Release 4 (Python 3). I can only find API docs for version 3.0 and it seems that there has been some depreciation between releases.

For example API docs (for 3.0) state that  `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist` should have a method `pprint`. Which does not appear in the source code and is not a method.

Is there anywhere where I can get updated docs OR can I generate these myself? The documentation under `?nltk.ConditionalFreqDist` is also a little thin and does not enumerate the methods.

Also (aside) is it not more conventional to depreciate methods rather than remove them completely between minor releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can browse code of nltk in version you want at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/3.0a4 ConditionalFreqDist is in file probability.py - you can also switch to older versions.

As far as I know nltk documentation is generated using sphinx: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html

According to your last question, yes it is.